# MVC: Is it a crime to call models directly from a view

Tags: model-view-controller

Is it a crime to call models directly from a view on purpose of displaying data?

For example, let's imagine that we have N dropdown lists in a partial view. These lists are to be filled by the values from M different models. Values come from some model properties and methods that may or may not query a database. I will use pseudocode.

**Way 1**. Call models from a partial view.

```
dropDownList(formModel, attribute1, Model1::someListFunction());
dropDownList(formModel, attribute2, Model2::someListFunction());
....
dropDownList(formModel, attributeN, ModelM::someListFunction());
```

**Way 2**. Fetch all needed list data in a controller and pass everything to a view (or a chain of views when one view calls other to construct itself).

Controller

```
...
list1 := Model1::someListFunction();
list2 := Model2::someListFunction();
...
listN := ModelM::someListFunction();
renderView("someView", array(list1=>list1, list2=>list2, ... listN=>listN));
```

someView

```
dropDownList(formModel, attribute1, list1);
dropDownList(formModel, attribute2, list2);
renderPartialView("_somePartialView1", array(list3=>list3, ...., listN=>listN);
```

And so on.

The drawback of way 2 is that we need to pull through the whole chain of views the whole "train" of all parameters (listP, listQ, ... listR) that are used in the last view of the chain. If we need to add another one parameter, we need to make changes in the whole chain of calls.

What are the drawbacks of way 1? I know that views are prohibited to make changes in models directly, but what if to call models just on purpose of displaying the view?

Answer (score 1):

My teacher says View is allowed to directly call model in some cases.

Quoting from wikipedia -->

```
"A view requests information from the model 
that it uses to generate an output representation to the user."
```

You can see the diagram on wikipedia page, model is sending data directly to view [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

and another diagram [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/MVC.gif)

Answer (score 0):

this is highly opinionated but few my remarks.

**Ad solution 1**:
depending on `someListFunction` it might not be possible e.g. to call DB since the connection was already closed by controller (e.g. hibernate lazy collections) etc. Any (unlikely but possible) error handling there might be worse to track (have you ever seen stacktrace from JSP page??). But if it is just some simple "transient" data model like `getFullName()` when model has `firstName` and `lastName` it is perfectly okey.

**Ad solution 2**:
If your view is that "complex", your model class can be complex as well. If you don't know yet a whole "train", build your model in generic enough way. First of all why it is bad to pass whole (sub)model to partial view when your partial view will then request only relevant information (e.g. `list3` etc).  This way if you want to extend your model, you don't have to change all the "train". Or implement it in even more generic way (if appropriate!!!) e.g. kind of map/dictionary/context object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's ok as long as you call model methods only for helping with the generation of the view.

However, there may be a better solution to this, so you're not dependent on the model as much. It's called ViewModel and Its role is to be a mediator between the view and the model. It aggregates the necessary properties and methods from the model (or even multiple models) for the purposes of the view. Your views know only about this mediator and the model isn't affected or referenced directly in any way.